# how to suppress powershell runas confirmation popup

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

When I run the following script

```
start-process powershell -verb runas -argument script.ps1
```

Windows will prompt with confirmation popup "Do you want to allow this app to change your device?" I can click either Yes or No.

However I am running remote Windows init on EC2 instance. When the powershell scripts runs, I have no way to interact with Windows. Is there any way to suppress such prompt so that it can continue silently?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** 
The content in script.ps1 is similar like this.

```
$DomainAdminFullUser = $DomainNetBIOSName + '\' + $DomainAdminUser
$DomainAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $DomainAdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$DomainAdminCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($DomainAdminFullUser, $DomainAdminSecurePassword)

$CreateFolderPs={
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Using:FolderPath -Name $Using:FolderName
}
Invoke-Command -Scriptblock $CreateFolderPs -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $DomainAdminCreds -ArgumentList $FolderPath,$FolderName

$CreateSharePs={
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    New-SmbShare -Name $Using:ShareName -Path $Using:Path -FullAccess $Using:FullAccessUser
}
Invoke-Command -Scriptblock $CreateSharePs -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $DomainAdminCreds
```

Comment: so ... what is in the script that is triggering that message/

Comment: Can you try with `-force`?

Comment: I tried `-force` already. It gave invalid parameter error.